# how too get the item from data base on list item click according to position of list

Tags: android

I want fetch the value save in list view according to position ..
Sir actualy i took help form NOTEPAD tutorial for adding the new item below in list view ...
now i want to fetch the item according to position in list view from onlist item click event what to do..
is it possible sir pls see my code what to do on list item click ignore comment part on " on list item click"

Thanks for help in advance....

```
 public class planner extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;
    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Long mRowId;
    private ServerResponce AllList;
    // private DeviceListAdapter AllList;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listonruntime);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        saveState();
        fillData();

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        String responce = null ;

    }
    private void fillData() {
        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBER};

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.toptext,R.id.middletext,R.id.circle};

       SimpleCursorAdapter notes =   
                                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, notesCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(notes);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

//      @Override
//    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
//    {
//        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
//        saveState();
//        outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
//    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
       // ServerResponce servresp=new ServerResponce();
       String responceId = Activity1.getData();
        String responceno = Activity2.getData();
        String city = cabbookingapplication.Selection;
        String area = cabbookingapplication.Selection2;
        String exactadd  = cabbookingapplication.Selection3;
        String nearby = cabbookingapplication.Selection4;
        private void saveState() {
        String title =("FROM LOC::"+city+","+area+","+exactadd+","+nearby);
        String body = ("TO LOC::"+city+","+area+","+exactadd+","+nearby);
        String number = (""+responceno+",,"+responceId);
            if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body, number);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body,number);
            }
        }

    **@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, thisID);
        String resposponseid = Activity2.getData();

        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(notesCursor);




        //  Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItemId(position);
        //    String c = ((Cursor) notes).getString(position);
        //       String ssssss= c.getString(position);
       String device_name = (String) ((Cursor)getListAdapter()).getString(position);
//        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//        bundle.putString("NAME", device_name);

       // String device_name = (String) (planner.this). getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        //response.get(position);
        //ArrayList respCode<String> = new Arraylist<String>();
        // add("response");
        //String ssss[]={sss};
        // Object o = (String) (Notepadv3.this).getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        // String pen = o.toString();
          Toast.makeText(this, "this row responceid is= " +  device_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 //        Object o =  this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different options.

**First option**

The last parameter of the onListItemClick() method `long thisID` is a unique id of the clicked item from the database. But this id is only usable when the cursor you bound to the adapter contains a column named `_id` which must contains a unique id for each item. You can then query the database for an item with this unique id. Don't mix this up with the position argument which only tells you the position of the item within the list, this value has nothing to do with the item's data id in the database.

**Second option**

As you get the view object of the currently selected item, you can extract the values from the view by searching for the view element which holds the name of the device.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID) {
     TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.middletext);      
     String deviceName = title.getText();
}
```